# How to prevent change state when Ionic "onHold" gesture is fired

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have a list of items with **`href`** that goes to an specific page of every item, and also has a **`onHold`** gesture that displays an action sheet with some options (delete and ...).

I wrote this angular Directive, But It Doesn't work! page changed after I release my finger on items.

```
app.directive("myOnHold", ['$ionicGesture', function ($ionicGesture) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
           $ionicGesture.on('hold', function (event) {
              event.preventDefault();
           }, $element)
        }
    }
}]);
```

Now, how to prevent change state(page) when **`onHold`** gesture is fired?

Comment: ionic and its occasional quirks. I have had success with using event.stopImmediatePropagation() and event.stopPropagation();

Comment: @Ladmerc It doesn't work. You mean: `$ionicGesture.on('hold', function (event) {
                  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                  event.stopPropagation();
               }, $element);`
yes?

Comment: have you checked it the html calls this directive? Try a `console.log` in the `.on('hold'..` to see if it gets logged

Comment: @Ladmerc Yes I called directive, and log the console is OK

Comment: Last thing I can think about is to replace href with ui-sref. Also try combining `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` with `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: @Ladmerc No, It doesn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: I just tested it and inspected the gesture property. This worked for me:

event.gesture.stopDetect();
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
event.stopPropagation();

Also ionic has a utility directive you can use on the item: ion-stop-event="hold"